# Facing some errors in c++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am writing a program in c++11 and I have faced some problems. I am new to c++11 programming, while I used to develop in c earlier, but I want to be familiar with the new facilities of c++.

I will present you below the contentious part of code explaining where are the errors and what kind of them I get.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// A struct describing a product.
typedef struct Products
{
    string category;
    string name;
    float price;
} Product;

inline void scenario1(int num_cashiers)
{
    extern vector<Product> products; // It is a vector(a pseudo-second dimension) of products which will be used for each customer
    extern vector<vector<Product> products> customers; // A vector containing all customers
    vector<vector<vector<Product> products> customers> cashiers(num_cashiers); // A vector describing the supermarket cashiers declaring a queue of customers for each cashier

    ...

}
```

Error 1: At the second line of the function scenario1(int num_cashiers): template argument 1 is invalid

Error 2: At the second line of the function scenario1(int num_cashiers): template argument 2 is invalid

Error 3: At the second line of the function scenario1(int num_cashiers): invalid type in declaration before ';' token

Error 4: At the third line of the function scenario1(int num_cashiers): template argument 1 is invalid

Error 5: At the third line of the function scenario1(int num_cashiers): template argument 2 is invalid

Error 6: At the third line of the function scenario1(int num_cashiers): template argument 1 is invalid //Same error again

Error 7: At the third line of the function scenario1(int num_cashiers): template argument 2 is invalid //Same error again

Error 8: At the third line of the function scenario1(int num_cashiers): invalid type in declaration before '(' token

So, where am I wrong and what do I have to do to fix the errors?

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: I am not sure if in C++11 you can put names within the declaration like you did. shoukd be similar to this `vector<vector<vector<Product>>> cashiers`

Comment: What on earth is this - `vector<vector<Product> products>`?

Comment: Come back to us when you get something to compile

Comment: @EdHeal As far as I can see you seem to be a kind of god who never makes mistakes or is born with planted knowledge from the very beginning of your life. Every advice, answer or comment is accepted (otherwise I would not ask for your help), but I would like to see some kind of respect. With all respects

Comment: @Praetorian I would like to create a kind of vector of vectors. I do not know whether this is the right way to do it. Is there something that you would advice me to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if in C++11 you can put names within the declaration like you did. Also as @EdHeal commented, should not use extern in an inline function.

This should work:

```
inline void scenario1(int num_cashiers) // why inline?
{
    vector<Product> products;
    vector<vector<Product>> customers; 
    vector<vector<vector<Product>>> cashiers(num_cashiers);

    ...

}
```

Comment: I would imagine that this would not be inlined anyway

Comment: @E Will see, let him speak

Comment: First of all before the above mentioned errors I had got a few more. To solve them(or maybe avoid them) I found that I had to declare the first two vectors as extern(I don't like extern or static keywords as well). Moreover, I had written the above part of code(like @FirstStep wrote) and the errors I mentioned in my post occurred. Finally, I use the "inline" keyword for optimization purposes.

Comment: @FirstStep Thank you for your willingness to make some stuff clear to me.

Comment: @FirstStep I found what was going wrong. By mistake, I had forgot customers into the vector declaration

Comment: @jim Cool. Glad we were able to help. Feel free to ask another question or to edit this question if my answer didn't answer your question :)